# Change hr style in HTML page

Tags: html, css, horizontal-line

I tried changing the `<hr>` tag with CSS using:

```
hr { color:whitesmoke}
```

But it doesn't affect my HTML at all. Is there a way to change the horizontal line's color to a different color than the default one using CSS? For performance purposes, I don't want to use an img (horizontal line in the color I want with `max-width: 100%`) but some CSS rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appearance of `<hr>` in the browser is based on border styles and not dictated by the `color` property. Therefore, try using `border-color` instead:

```css
hr {
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```css
hr { border: 0px; border-bottom: 1px solid whitesmoke; }
```

```html
<hr/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
hr {border-top: 1px solid whitesmoke;}
```

```html
<hr>
```